# Get charge id associated with Stripe checkout session

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe checkout sessions. I am capturing 'checkout.session.completed' webhook. I need to know charge id associated with the session so I can refund the customer later. I am not finding any reference to charge object in the session object.

How can I get charge object associated with checkout session?

I tried capturing charge object in charge.succeeded webhook, but it doesn't have any reference to the price object customer used to purchase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A completed Checkout Session will have an associated [PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_intent), which in turn has a [list of Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-charges) associated with it.

Comment: This was not at all obvious. When did Stripe get so confusing?!

Comment: Your second link is broken. I don't think you can go from PaymentIntent to charge anymore. https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object

Comment: More here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/issues/927#issuecomment-1353522284